# How to Open and Automatically Pan to a Specific SVG ID on a Large Drawing

Tags: javascript, html, svg, filemaker

At the risk of sounding like a rookie, which I am, how can I change the default opening position of an SVG drawing? The drawing is quite large -- 2130 x 3100 px -- larger than my screen area, and has IDs that define paths. The paths outline the various rooms on an architectural floor plan.

Tried to paste the entire SVG code, to help illustrate the point and to request help from readers. Is there a way I can attach it? For now, only snippets (of random rooms) are included.

Currently, the file defaults to the top left corner of the drawing, which I'd like to change to open on "myID". For example, when the given SVG is opens, user sees top left rooms P117, P118, P119. What if I wanted user to see bottom right room P124, or near-center room P113? That is, can I use a room ID to specify the opening position of the SVG? And can I do it internally?

Maybe I should mention that I'm using this in a "web viewer" that understands SVG, HTML, and javascript, but it's not a browser per se. Those of you familiar with FileMaker will know what I mean. I'm thinking this matters in case some of you suggest external file references, which won't help.

Anyway, here's the SVG. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Leo

```
<path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#250000;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
       d="m 1146.9779,223.87304 c 0,51.75805 0,103.51609 0,155.27414 164.7957,0 329.5913,0 494.387,0 0,-20.01962 0,-40.03925 0,-60.05887 -164.7957,-31.73842 -329.5913,-63.47685 -494.387,-95.21527 z"
       id="P119"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       inkscape:label="#P119" />
<path
       style="fill:none;stroke:none"
       d="m 1149.6255,377.00439 c 59.8716,0.24414 119.7432,0.48829 179.6148,0.73243 -0.3382,30.85668 -0.6763,61.71337 -1.0145,92.57005 -7.8876,0 -15.7751,0 -23.6627,0 0,20.43204 0,40.86409 0,61.29613 6.798,0 13.5961,0 20.3941,0 0,6.31056 0,12.62111 0,18.93167 -49.8049,0 -99.6099,0 -149.4148,0 0,13.80389 0,27.60779 0,41.41168 -9.0332,0 -18.0665,0 -27.0997,0 0,-44.02138 0,-88.04275 0,-132.06413 7.0612,0 14.1223,0 21.1835,0 0,-10.53522 0,-21.07043 0,-31.60565 -6.3287,0 -12.6575,0 -18.9862,0 -0.3382,-17.09073 -0.6763,-34.18145 -1.0145,-51.27218 z"
       id="P118"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       inkscape:label="#P118" />
<path
       style="fill:none;stroke:none"
       d="m 1184.3315,559.32378 c 47.1194,0 94.2387,0 141.3581,0 -0.4883,19.09995 -0.9765,38.1999 -1.4648,57.29985 -47.1194,-0.73243 -94.2387,-1.46485 -141.3581,-2.19728 0.4883,-18.36752 0.9765,-36.73505 1.4648,-55.10257 z"
       id="P117"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       inkscape:label="#P117" />


<path
       style="fill:none;stroke:none"
       d="m 2763.9405,2607.0739 c 0,80.4835 0,160.967 0,241.4505 39.2273,0 78.4545,0 117.6818,0 0,-80.4835 0,-160.967 0,-241.4505 -39.2273,0 -78.4545,0 -117.6818,0 z"
       id="P124"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />


<path
       style="fill:none;stroke:none"
       d="m 1805.24,1677.2866 c 0,41.4253 0,82.8507 0,124.276 28.575,0 57.1501,0 85.7251,0 0,-41.5944 0,-83.1889 0,-124.7833 -28.575,0.1691 -57.1501,0.3382 -85.7251,0.5073 z"
       id="P113"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a rookie question at all. If you haven't already, you should state a viewBox on your SVG element. Given your dimensions it should look something like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2130 3100">
  ...
</svg>
```

If you are familiar with drawing applications, the viewBox is the equivalent of dragging the zoom tool over the canvas. The first two digits will be the `x` and `y` and the last two digits will be the height and width of the zoom "rectangle".

Now, suppose you want to move the viewport to room `P113`, this it what you would do:

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var room = document.getElementById('P113');
var bbox = room.getBBox();
svg.setAttribute("viewBox",  bbox.x + " " + bbox.y + " 2130 3100");
```

This will actually display room `P113` to the top left corner. If you want to center the room in the viewport you can do so by calculating the viewport dimensions and the room dimensions, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you Duopixel. I tried your suggestion, but I couldn't get it to work. The viewBox="0 0 2130 3100" worked in terms of providing a bird's eye view, but I don't want to "zoom" out to see it all. I want to initialize on a specific room. Maybe if you see the whole file... it's in my dropbox https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15795405/A3.00-P1_2012-01-21.svg   Thanks again.

Comment: Set `2130 3100` of the viewBox to be the same size as the containing div, so if it's width 900 height 600 your viewBox should be something like viewBox="0 0 900 600". Then apply the javascript with the corresponding numbers.

Comment: Hi Duopixel. Thank you. I changed the width and height. Copied th javascript

Comment: Hi Duopixel. Thank you for your help. I changed the width and height. Does this look right for the javascript? I put it in the <head>.
<script type="text/javascript">
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var room = document.getElementById('P113');
var bbox = room.getBBox();
svg.setAttribute("viewBox",  bbox.x + " " + bbox.y + " 900 600");
</script>
Still doesn't work. Can I pay you to edit the file? I can be reached in Toronto 416-388-7894 or dicroceleo@gmail.com.  Thanks again for your help on this this =L=